# How to detect timeout on read of socket with gnat.sockets.Receive_Socket ?

Tags: sockets, ada, gnat

I am using the [Gnat Sockets](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Libraries/GNAT.Sockets) package.
I have a server-side socket that has been created & initialised with the following:

```
   GNAT.Sockets.Create_Socket(...);
```

...

```
   GNAT.Sockets.Set_Socket_Option
     (Socket => Server,
      Option => (Name => GNAT.Sockets.Receive_Timeout,
                 Timeout => Listner_Timeout));
```

...

```
   GNAT.Sockets.Listen_Socket(...);
   GNAT.Sockets.Accept_Socket(...);
```

All well and good sofar, but when it is time to use :

```
   GNAT.Sockets.Receive_Socket(...);
```

I have no idea how to detect if my socket has timed out, or read some data when it returns. 
Do I need to use the `Check_Selector` method (It seems a bit heavy for this use, and if so does this interact with the time out set in the `Set_Socket_Option` call)?

Thanks,

Comment: If you're interfacing with some external system using sockets, then yes, you'll have to deal with all this. But if this is for some intra-system comms within an app you're developing, take a look at something like [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) ([Ada binding](http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:ada)) or [YAMI4](http://www.inspirel.com/yami4). These handle all that detailed socket stuff for you, letting you focus on the communications/message protocol you want. I've adopted ZeroMQ as much as possible, and my goal in open source development is to never have to write socket code again :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In any case, the Timeout parameter on Check_Selector does what it sounds like you want. You invoke Check_Selector(), and when it returns look at the status. If the Status is Complete, you've gotten "activity" such as data (assuming you're reading) or the other end of a socket closed, if Expired the selector timed out, and if Aborted then the selector was commanded to prematurely terminate via Abort_Selector().

I typically put the socket reading, including the Check_Selector() invocation, in a task so as not to block the rest of the app, and allow for an externally initiated Abort_Selector. In fact, I rarely use a timeout, I just loop the Check/Read on the socket, and when I no longer need to read the socket, like when shutting down, just call Abort_Selector() to finish it off.

Comment: This looks like the way to go. No accept until it get it working though :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I read about someone using asynchronous `select` to handle the timeout case... something like:

```
loop
  select
    -- HANDLE SOCKET RECEPTION
   or
    delay 7.0; -- Wait seven seconds to timeout.
  end select;
end loop;
```

**`Note:` The above is from memory, it is NOT syntax-checked or compiled.**

Comment: This looks like it is doing what i think the 'Receive_Socket' procedure should be doing internally. It will probably work, but is not the 'GNAT.Sockets' solution i was looking for.

Comment: You are thinking of [asynchronous transfer of control](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-7-4.html). And it does work in this context on Mac OS X, but I don't think it's portable for detecting socket timeout (depends on interaction between threads/tasks/sockets).

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but it [looks as though](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setsockopt.html) you should get a `Socket_Error` exception with, maybe, `EWOULDBLOCK`.

This might not work too well if the data is merely trickling through, since the timeout is going to be reset every time *some* data arrives.

Update: I tried this on Mac OS X, and got `GNAT.SOCKETS.SOCKET_ERROR: [35] Resource temporarily unavailable`. [35] is `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` (Darwin uses the same value for both, so `GNAT.Sockets` deliberately makes the ambiguous report).

Answer (score 0):

By reading the `Gnat.Sockets` package spec (btw, the one you linked to does not support `Receive_Timeout`), my guess is `Socket_Error` is raised, that resolves (with `Resolve_Exception`) to `Connection_Timed_Out`.

Another possibility is that `Receive_Socket` returns with `Last` set to `Item'First - 1`, as if the socket was closed by peer.

Comment: Correct about the linked package, I guess wikipedia has not been updated!